# How to execute mocha test suite for specific amount of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a requirement like have to execute the below test suite for specific amount time.

```
  describe("sample test script", function(){

      it("sample test case", function(done) {
           //---test case statements
           done();
      });    
  });
```

I have tried using While loop as below code. But the thing is iterations are happening continuously without completion of `describe` statement. I want to wait for the iteration till `describe` block execution and continue the loop. How will do I this thing

var testCaseTimeDuration= new Date(new Date().getTime() + (config.testCaseExecutionTime * 60000));

```
    while(testCaseDuration > new Date()) { 

     describe("sample test script", function(){

              it("sample test case", function(done) {
                   //---test case statements
                   done();
              });    
          });
    }
```

Comment: Not understanding your requirement. Do you mean you want the test cases to stop running after a certain amount of time (i.e; timeout), or do you want to start the test cases only after a certain time has passed? Or did I miss the question completely and your requirement is something else?

Comment: @theapologist I want to execute the test cases loop for a specific amount of time.